# get_post_format() function not working Wordpress

Tags: php, custom-post-type

I am trying to get post format with the code below

```
$post_id = $post->ID;
                $post_format = get_post_format($post_id);
```

but it does not provide any response than i tried to check with this code if it provide any result but my code does not go in to this condition.

```
if(has_post_format('standard')){
                print_r($post_id);
            }
```

Please tell me if i am wrong anywhere or there is any other method to get post format.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the function `has_post_format()` providing the post's ID as second parameter? https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_format

Answer (score 0):

For "$post_id = $post->ID;" to work, you would have to first call the global $post variable `global $post;` to be able to retrieve the ID outside of the loop.
So, the first code should be:

```
global $post;    
$post_id = $post->ID;
$post_format = get_post_format($post_id);
```